# How to pass COUNT using WITH in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following cypher query -

```
MATCH(from: GContact)
WHERE NOT from:migrationComplete
WITH from
LIMIT 10
SET from:migrationComplete
WITH from, COUNT(from) AS booleanCount
MATCH (from)-[r:has]->(to: GEmail)
WITH from, to, booleanCount
MERGE (from)-[r:contactHasEmail]->(to)
RETURN booleanCount
```

I want the query to return the number of `from` found after `SET`, which would be `<=10`.

However, what the query returns the number of matches found in `MATCH (from)-[r:has]->(to: GEmail)`. Is there a way to pass on the original count all the way through and return?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return the aggregated and un-aggregated value as a general fact.

But you can aggregate and distribute again with collect:

```
MATCH(from: GContact)
WHERE NOT from:migrationComplete
WITH from
LIMIT 10
SET from:migrationComplete
WITH COLLECT(from) AS nodes
UNWIND nodes as from
WITH from, size(nodes) AS booleanCount
MATCH (from)-[r:has]->(to: GEmail)
WITH from, to, booleanCount
MERGE (from)-[r:contactHasEmail]->(to)
RETURN booleanCount
```

You could also just at the end use `RETURN count(distinct from) as booleanCount`

Comment: Doesn't seem like the query returns any records. It also seems that the new relations are not created.